# RandomAccessFile vs FileChannel.open(path);

Tags: java, io, nio

What kind of `FileChannel` object does the `FileChannel.open(path)` method return?

Is it still random access allowed as if it was as following?

```
RandomAccessFile ra = new RandomAccessFile("RandomIndeed","rw");
    FileChannel fc1 = ra.getChannel();
```

What's the difference between `fc1` and the following instance `fc`:

```
FileChannel fc = FileChannel.open(path);
```

Basically I would like to know what will be the differences between the 2 objects above-created, hence `fc1` and `fc`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The same object (sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl) is returned for both calls (for Unix filesystems at least).

Answer (score 3):

The `FileChannel` instance got from `RandomAccessFile` instance carries the random access behaviour of the object it's been created, in this case `fc1` is synced with `ra` object. You can see it's described in javadoc

> Changing the channel's position, whether explicitly or by reading or
>   writing bytes, will change the file position of the originating
>   object, and vice versa. Changing the file's length via the file
>   channel will change the length seen via the originating object, and
>   vice versa. Changing the file's content by writing bytes will change
>   the content seen by the originating object, and vice versa.

However the `FileChannel` instance which is created using `FileChannel.open()` which is `fc` doesn't have this behaviour. This is true for the `FileChannel` instances you got from Streams. It only guarantees that the view of the file is consistent among the objects created by the same program. Hope this might help you.

Comment: FileChannel implements SeekableByteChannel which serves to navigate a file "randomly". How come? It means that also fc have those methods belonging to the SeekableByteChannel interface.

Comment: @Rollerball, are you using JDK7 ? sorry I replied to your question refering the JDK 6 implementation. FileChannel doesn't implement SeekableByteChannel prior to 7 i think.

Answer (score 0):

i think the answer depends on the version of jdk

before jdk7,they are different on the randomAccess function

but after jdk7(included), they are same;